# Get post from database by user ID - PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My database:

[image: My database]

This is my php code for retrieve post: example `post.php?id=12` :

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once('../connection.php');
    include_once('../comments.php');
    include_once('../gallery.php');
    class Objects{
        //fetch all posts
        public function get_information(){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `post` LEFT JOIN post_gallery ON  post.post_id = post_gallery.user WHERE post_cat = "Cars"');
            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
            //fetch post data by post id 
            public function fetch_data($pid){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `post` LEFT JOIN post_gallery ON  post.post_id = post_gallery.user WHERE post_cat = "Cars"');
            $query->BindValue(1,$pid);
            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetch();
        }
    }
?>
```

This code is for retrieve `posts` and `post_gallery` information and images. Problem is when user click on random post and go to `post.php?id=12` on that page will be displayed all posts defined by `post_cat = "Cars"` not by `?id=12`. Anyone know where im wrong?

Comment: And what's the meaning of `post.post_id = post_gallery.user`?

Comment: Are you actually using `?id=12` somewhere in that code? Couldn't find anything. You're using `WHERE post_cat = "Cars"` in both methods

Comment: that mean post.post_id get post id from posts and post_gallery.user id of user who stored that into database. @u_mulder

Comment: Yes its called by this code ```<?php echo $post['post_id'] ?>``` with this i will get id of post in this case its ```?id=12``` @kerbholz

Comment: Confused I am! `<?php echo $post['post_id'] ?>` doesn't show anywhere in that code. Don't know what `$post` is. Don't know why `post_id` when the GET parameter is named `id`. `$query->BindValue(1,$pid);` What parameter should this bind to?